# Mounting a CIFS share respecting the mode but ignoring the UID/GID

Tags: linux, cifs

**Summary**

Is there a way to force the `file_mode=` and `dir_mode=` options to take effect even when UNIX Extensions are enabled, without completely disabling local permission checking like the `noperm` option does?

**Detail**

I am mounting a CIFS share from a remote host running Samba.  UNIX Extensions are enabled, so I can see the owner and the permissions (mode) on the local machine.

Since the UIDs on the server don't match my local machine, I am using the `uid=`, `gid=`, `forceuid` and `forcegid` options to make all files appear locally as the correct user.  This works fine.

However the server-side permissions allow full access (0777), so anyone on the local machine can see into the share.  I want to change the permissions so that only the `uid=` user specified in the mount options can access the share.

I can specify these values in the `file_mode=` and `dir_mode=` options, however these are ignored when UNIX Extensions are enabled.

I can only see two options:

1. Disable UNIX Extensions, which will make the permissions work.  However then symlinks can't be created on the share (and the `sfu` option doesn't help) so this is not practical.
2. Mount the share with the `noperm` option which ignores the permissions set (so no problems with accidentally setting the wrong perms) however this disables ALL permission checking so the share is still accessible by anyone on the local machine.
3. Mount the share within another folder and apply the permissions to that parent folder instead.  This is a bit dodgy so I'd rather fix the problem on the CIFS mount if I can!

So is there a way to force the `file_mode=` and `dir_mode=` options to take effect even when UNIX Extensions are enabled, while still having the resulting permissions enforced locally?